# UNIX find and replace using execdir and bash

Tags: regex, bash, unix, replace, find

I am new to scripting and have a requirement where I need to change the special characters from file and replace with some other character.

Below is the file name where I have to replace the `?` by `_`.

file - `21041159?74DECL?ARAÇÃO14581?5904289?6770700.pdf`

result - `21041159_74DECL_ARAÇÃO14581_5904289_6770700.pdf`

```
find . -depth -name '*\?*' -type f -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\?/_}"' -- {} \;
```

The above script changes the first occurrence of question mark to underscore but not from complete file name.

Please suggest what can be done?

Comment: Take a look at `rename` command and its regex feature.

Answer (score 2):

A simplified version of your question is:

> I can replace the *first* occurrence of a string in a bash variable with `${var/foo/bar}`.
>
> How can I replace *all* occurrences?

And the answer is to use double slash: `${var//foo/bar}`.

In context, it would be:

```
find . -depth -name '*\?*' -type f -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//\?/_}"' -- {} \;
                                                        # Here --^
```

Comment: Why did you take the wildcards out of the `-name` option?